Visual Studio Code Can't Read External SpringBoot Property file
In VS Code, Spring Boot application is starting fine if I keep the application.yaml file under src/main/resources folder. I tried to externalize the application.yaml file and updated vmArgs property in launch.json file to point to application.yaml file.
The application is not starting, mentioning - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.property'. Am I missing anything?
"test.property" is there in the app property file, I can confirm.
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "TestApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.test.Application",
            "projectName": "TestApplication",
            "vmArgs": ["-Dspring.config.location=/Users/Desktop/vscode-test/application.yaml"]
        }
    ]
}

2024-10-21 12:41:40.073 [restartedMain] ERROR [] o.s.boot.SpringApplication:859 - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.property' in value "${test.property}"


Found the issue! It is Not the launch.json configuration that is incorrect. In VS code, the "RUN AND DEBUG" button selected the "Current File", not the SpringBoot application start file that contains the main method.
It is a silly mistake, but it took me a day to fix!
